# Replace comma from decimal string in php

Tags: preg-replace

i want to replace comma from decimal string

For example:  i have a text

```
"Sample content 2.6g ident. 2um the 84.45gm with 2,8g and some 23.83 that it".
```

Expected output:

```
 "Sample content 2,6g ident. 2um the 84,45gm with 2,8g and some 23,83 that it".
```

Please suggest me how to replace comma from decimal in php

Comment: regular expression that searches for `digit.digit` and replaces it with `digit,digit`. Don't know how to do it in your language, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example test if the comma is surrounded by digits:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)~', ',', $str);
```